# In-App Purchase product ID invalid after metadata update

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I have been testing an app with in-app purchase. It has been working fine until today. I updated some of the metadata of the in-app purchase on iTunesConnect and saved it. Specifically it was the description of the in-app purchase. Since then, my product ID returns as invalid when I try to retrieve it in the app. The product ID is still the same as it always was and hasn't changed. Do I have to wait some time before it becomes valid again?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did take some time, but became valid again. I don't know if this was just a glitch in the in-app service or it required waiting. I have never had a problem again to this point.

Comment: You have to wait so the first thing I do is create the purchasable items before starting the development.